# Better VHOST management in Nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, virtual-hosts

My `nginx.conf` file is getting larger and large with dozens of vhosts repeating the same lines over and over. I was wondering if there is anyway to declare the following globally without having to repeat them for each project:

```
# Route all requests for non-existent files to index.php
if (!-e $request_filename) {
 rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ \.php($|/) {
 include fastcgi_params;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Comment: This question is more than likely better suited for serverfault...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file with the common setup for your vhosts (ie. vhost.conf). Wherever you would like to utilize this common setup, just include that vhost.conf-file.

```
server {
    include vhost.conf

    location /test {
        # Custom setup for /test
    }
}
```

Paths are relative to your nginx.conf-file, use absolute paths if specifying vhost.conf outside your nginx.conf-path. http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpMainModule#include